# JQuery click function not being set

Tags: jquery, event-handling, css-selectors

I want my links not to have the weird outline and the best way I found to solve this is have a "null link" to focus on after a click.  This works great when defining the onclick method inline the HTML but that is not ideal.  I wrote a quick jQuery snippet to do this instead, but I am having trouble getting it to work.  Here it is:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $j(document).ready(function () {
        //alert($j('#ml_table thead a').length);
        $j('#ml_table thead a').click( function (){
            $j('#null_link').focus(); return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Does anyone see any problems with this? The alert spits out 8 which is the correct number of anchor elements so I know the selector is working properly.  The [jQuery docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/click#fn) say that I don't have to iterate through the array of elements.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try css:

```
#ml_table thead a {
    outline:none;
}
```

And for IE:

```
$('#ml_table thead a').attr('hidefocus', true)
```

References:

- [hideFocus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533783%28VS.85%29.aspx)

But yeah, to answer your direct question the one click function is applied to the 8 anchors it found.

That `focus` trick looks kinda funky. If you really want to keep it you can try instead:

```
$j('#ml_table thead a').click(function () {
    $(this).blur();
    return false;
})
```

Comment: actually I think the issue is that I am using sortable which is overwriting the onclick function to sort the table...oops